# how to control input autofill list

Tags: javascript, html

How can I add/remove predicts to/from input autofill list?
Something like this:

```
<input id="myInput">
```

...

```
const predicts = document.getElementById('myInput').predicts;
console.log(predicts); // => ['one', 'two'] - get autofill predicts
document.getElementById('myInput').predicts.push('new-predict'); // add new 'new-predict' to autofill
document.getElementById('myInput').predicts.remove(1); // remove second predict from autofill
```

[image: Autofill list I want to control]

**Important**: I don't want to use external libs like jQuery autocomplete. I want to control *native* behavior.

Comment: Wait... so are you referring to the HTML5 [datalist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist)?

Comment: @JosephMarikle, no, I want to control native input autocomplete field.... I've added picture to the question

Comment: You're referring to the autofill that major browsers incorporate into form fields.  Unfortunately I don't believe you can't manipulate that list from a programmatic standpoint. It would be a major security risk to allow web applications to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at the specifications: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#autofilling-form-controls:-the-autocomplete-attribute

*User agents sometimes have features for helping users fill forms in, for example prefilling the user's address based on earlier user input. The autocomplete content attribute can be used to hint to the user agent how to, or indeed whether to, provide such a feature.*

so native behavior is to use earlier user input to build the autofill term list, not to let you control it: there are huge security implications on letting any website access user input history (ie: think about any random script on any random webpage reading your input history for fields named `username` or `password` and so on...).

If you do not like to use other native features as `datalist` nor use javascript ( jquery or your own) to duplicate autocomplete functionality, I think your only option is to resort to black hack techniques like this ( presented at black hack USA 2010 http://www.slideshare.net/jeremiahgrossman/breaking-browsers-hacking-autocomplete-blackhat-usa-2010/22 ) to fill the input history  ( see http://blog.jeremiahgrossman.com/2010/07/in-firefox-we-cant-read-auto-complete.html  ):

```
function fillAutoComp() {

// random data, nothing important
var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000000);

// set some arbitrary data to the text field
document.getElementById('data').value = “Spoof-” + num;

// submit the form, over and over and over again
setTimeout("document.getElementById('me').submit(); fillAutoComp();",2);
}
```

my 2 cents in the end is to avoid these hacks and go with one of the many alternatives to native autocomplete attribute

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;)

In this case what you can do is use `datalist`; With this you will see the items you added to the `datalist` as `option` and you can select option from here;

One more thing you can add `autocomplete="true"` to instruct browser don't show if there is any prefill data;

Start typing and it will show you the options;

```html
<input type="text" list="predicts" autocomplete="true" />
<datalist id="predicts">
  <option>Predict 1</option>
  <option>Predict 2</option>
  <option>Predict 3</option>
  <option>Predict 4</option>
  <option>Predict N</option>
</datalist>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use jquery autocomplete plugin

https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

or try this link if you are using some server side codeing

http://tutsforweb.blogspot.in/2012/05/auto-complete-text-box-with-php-jquery.html

Hope it helps you